# Sorting array with numbers from text file in C?

Tags: c

So the task is to open a text file(WITHOUT fopen, using only commands in terminal/console), put the info into an array, sort the array(numbers are originally in random order "4,12,2,4") and then then all the sorted data must print on a second txt file.Now I made myself a program but apparently isn't correct, can you tell me where I am wrong, I am using qsort for the first time so I am not expert at this, previously used bubble sort, thanks in advance!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//first time using qsort function.
int array[1024];
int array_counter=0;

int compare (const void * num1, const void * num2)
{
   return (*(int*)num1 - *(int*)num2);
}

int main ()
{
   int i;
   char c;
   while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
   {
      if(c >='0' && c <='9' )
      {
         i = atoi(&c);
         array[array_counter] = i;
         array_counter++;
      }
   }
   int counter;
   qsort(array, array_counter, sizeof(array[array_counter]), compare);
   for(counter = 0; counter < array_counter; counter++)
   {
   printf ("%d", array[array_counter]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's a better chance of us helping you if you help us, by providing more information than "apparently isn't correct". I can tell you that `atoi(&c)` is wrong.

Comment: why getchar()?
you don't expect input with more digits?

Comment: atoi(&c) may cause memory corruptions/access to invalid memory...

Comment: Why do you think the code is incorrect? (knowing at least approximately where the problem is located is always the first step towards finding it). Also, indenting the code would help us (and you) understand it.

Comment: There is no code to handle whitespace and/or newlines as delimiters between numbers?

Comment: This task is for auto checking and the judge says it's wrong answer.I think I am sorting with qsort correctly as I used c references but probably I have mistakes in my while cycle.Sorry for not letting you know at first place.

Comment: note: getchar() return value is int.

Answer (score 0):

```
   while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
   {
      if(c >='0' && c <='9' )
      {
         i = atoi(&c);
         array[array_counter] = i;
         array_counter++;
      }
   }
```

This is wrong. You need to put the chars into a buffer, null-terminate it, and then call `atoi` on the buffer. Or you can use `scanf` instead of your own loop;

```
printf ("%d", array[array_counter]);
```

You want "%d\n", otherwise the numbers will be smooshed together.

> the judge says it's wrong answer

You would know it's the wrong answer if you did some testing before submitting it ... check that the numbers that you're putting into the array have the right values, then check that the output looks right.

Answer (score 0):

I found several mistakes in you code so here is the working code with explanations in as comments (see man page of [qsort](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//first time using qsort function.
int array[1024];
int array_counter=0;

int compare (const void * num1, const void * num2)
{
   return (*(int*)num1 - *(int*)num2);
}

int main ()
{
   int i;
   char c;
   // use '0' terminated string  for passing it to atoi as this is what it is expecting
   // not only a pointer to char
   char buf[2];
   buf[1] = '\0'; // terminate the string with a '0' since you want only to have digits in your buffer
   // you may use something else (scanf for example) to read number of more than one digit)
   while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
   {
      if(c >='0' && c <='9' )
      {
         // put the char in buf
         buf[0] = c;
         // pass that buf to atoi (even if &c is satisfiying the signature of atoi it is not null terminated)
         i = atoi(buf);
         array[array_counter] = i;
         array_counter++;
      }
   }

   // arguments passed to qsort were wrong (second and third)
   // first is the array (or where the sorting should start)
   // second is the size of one element in the array thus sizof(int)
   // third is the number of the array elements to be sorted
   // the compare function
   qsort(array, sizeof(int), array_counter, compare);

   int counter;
   for(counter = 0; counter < array_counter; counter++)
   {
       // use counter to access array elements not array_counter, array_counter ist the index of the next free element and is always 0
       printf ("%d ", array[counter]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Sample text file `digits.txt`

```
2 1 6 4
```

execute command

```
out.exe < digits.txt
```

output

```
1 2 4 6
```